# How to determine switching to regular job after no contracts for a while?

Tags: attracting-clients

I have posted numerous questions about my work being very slow ([here](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1235/bad-rating-has-decreased-my-chances-of-getting-work-how-can-i-recover-from-bad) [here](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/application-getting-constant-declined) and [here](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1804/how-to-tell-client-that-i-can-fix-their-problem-in-a-cover-letter-when-they-hav)), and now it seems like work has dried up or died. The reason I say "died" is because for months, I haven't been contacted by any client; I've sent hundreds of applications. I even hired a Resume Writer, followed her instructions and got nothing. I used to earn good money, even on smaller projects.

I understand that in at the start of the year, people were recovering from Christmas budget expenses, and work might be slow; but I haven't been able to see any change in my line of work. I have been rated highly (top 10%) for Wordpress development, among other things.

How do I determine if I should go back to working in an office? If I did, what would I tell the employer about my 3 years gap in my CV? It's been 5 months since I've been able to make any decent money.

Comment: Hi Nofel, I edited your question to keep it more to the point. Asking questions that don't seem to help others is not really something that works well here, so I changed it to "how do I determine if I should ...". This should help more visitors, and also get some better quality answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such question can only be answered by you. I also had a gap and I am still now earning as much as I was earning in the last quarter of 2013. I solved this gap by working real low wages (30% of my real hourly rate) so that I am not just on zero and covering the remaining money from the safe fund. I guess such things happen. I managed to return my work load to the one from the last quarter.

Now, no one here can answer what went wrong with you. Either high rates or bad clients or wrong website or bad previous work, etc. If you have chance to get a quick job, then I suggest you do it. Even with such job you can still maintain freelancing by working 20 hours a week. I know many people do that.

How shall you determine if you should return? Do you support anyone? Are you in lack of money? Will you be on $0 in 1 month? If yes, then get a money gaining job asap.

With a steady income, you will be able to seek for good jobs and long term clients. When you find one, seek for quality, not speed. Quality work will get you more clients. Aim to pixel perfection, not quick work. Don't post 10 bids a day - post 1 well planned for prospective client and with bids + samples that will shake your potential client. Since you will be less stressed and will have money inflow, I think you will be able to write better proposals. I write best proposals, when I have good project and when I am satisfied.